# Create CompositeArray of CompositeType without using sqlalchemy_utils

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, alembic, asyncpg

Within my FastAPI, SQLAlchemy, Alembic project, I was using `postgresql` engine, and now I'm trying to migrate to async with `postgresql+asyncpg`.
The issue here is that one of my DB schemas has this structure:

```py
class MyTable(...):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    tridimensional = Column(CompositeArray(
            CompositeType(
                'tridimensional_type', [
                    Column('x', Numeric(4, 0), nullable=False, default=0),
                    Column('y', Numeric(4, 0), nullable=False),
                    Column('z', Numeric(4, 0), nullable=False),
                ]
            ),
        ),
    )
```

Since this was relying entirely on `sqlalchemy_utils.types.pg_composite` (Both `CompositeArray` and `CompositeType`) and this does not have support to `register_composites` for `postgresql+asyncpg`, I was wondering (if possible) how to:

- Create my own `sqlalchemy.types.UserDefinedType` that involves this tridimensional type
- Add it to an alembic migration
- Create a column using it within an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to figure it out kinda *using* `CompositeType`:
I created this two classes:

1. To access elements from a dict using the dot operator `.`

```py
class Dotdict(dict):
    __getattr__ = dict.get
    __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__
```

And the inherited class to process it from

```py
class AsyncCompositeType(CompositeType):
    # async sessions return asyncpg.Record not the type define in sqlalchemy_utils
    # these wrappers returns a dict when the composite type is loaded using an async session
    # see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/custom_types.html#typedecorator-recipes
    def result_processor(self, dialect, coltype):
        def process(record):
            if isinstance(record, asyncpg.Record):  # handle async sqlalchemy session
                return Dotdict(record)
            return record
        return process
```

Finally, your table would only be changed to:

```py
class MyTable(...):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    tridimensional = Column(CompositeArray(
            AsyncCompositeType(
                'tridimensional_type', [
                    Column('x', Numeric(4, 0), nullable=False, default=0),
                    Column('y', Numeric(4, 0), nullable=False),
                    Column('z', Numeric(4, 0), nullable=False),
                ]
            ),
        ),
    )
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon the same issue and came up with this (probably incomplete and not very thoroughly tested) [implementation](https://gist.github.com/SF-300/ad5022f9be3557334d41c0b4c8a6dd83). It's also based on ideas from [sqlalchemy-utils](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sqlalchemy_utils/types/pg_composite.html) but avoids hard psycopg2 dependency.

Mind that there is no `CompositeArray` equivalent. It [seems](https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-utils/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#0380-2021-12-21) that no custom type is actually *required* for such arrays. The same functionality can be achieved by explicitly declaring dimensions and item type of your `ARRAY` of composites and SQLAlchemy will properly pass each array entry to `result_processor` of item's `UserDefinedType` (and hence to `process_result_value` of `TypeDecorator` wrapper).

All in all, the following code demonstrates intended usage (tested on Python 3.11 and SQLAlchemy 1.4):

```python
import asyncio
import dataclasses
import pprint
from contextlib import AsyncExitStack
from decimal import Decimal

import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql as sa_pg

import composite

if __name__ == "__main__":
    async def main():
        metadata = sa.MetaData()

        demo_composite_type = composite.define_composite(
            "demo_composite",
            metadata,
            ("field1", sa.TEXT),
            ("field2", sa.Numeric),
        )

        # NOTE: The following class might be omitted if `asyncpg.Record` as a return type is sufficient for your
        #       needs and there is no need to convert items to some custom (data)class.
        class demo_composite_type(sa.types.TypeDecorator):
            impl, cache_ok = demo_composite_type, True

            python_type = dataclasses.make_dataclass(
                "DemoComposite",
                [name for name in demo_composite_type.fields],
            )

            def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
                if value is not None:
                    return self.python_type(**value)

        async with AsyncExitStack() as deffer:
            pg_engine = sa.ext.asyncio.create_async_engine(
                "postgresql+asyncpg://scott:tiger@localhost/test"
            )
            deffer.push_async_callback(pg_engine.dispose)

            pg_conn = await deffer.enter_async_context(
                pg_engine.connect()
            )

            await pg_conn.run_sync(metadata.create_all)
            deffer.push_async_callback(pg_conn.run_sync, metadata.drop_all)

            values_stmt = (
                sa.sql.Values(
                    sa.column("column1", sa.TEXT),
                    sa.column("column2", sa.Numeric),
                )
                .data([
                    ("1", Decimal(1)),
                    ("2", Decimal(2)),
                ])
                .alias("samples")
            )

            result = (await pg_conn.execute(
                sa.select([
                    sa.func.array_agg(
                        sa.cast(
                            sa.tuple_(
                                values_stmt.c.column1,
                                values_stmt.c.column2,
                            ),
                            demo_composite_type,
                        ),
                        type_=sa_pg.ARRAY(
                            demo_composite_type,
                            dimensions=1,
                        ),
                    )
                    .label("array_of_composites")
                ])
                .select_from(
                    values_stmt
                )
            )).scalar_one()

            pprint.pprint(result)


    asyncio.run(main())
```

Output of the sample above is the following:

```
[DemoComposite(field1='1', field2=Decimal('1')),
 DemoComposite(field1='2', field2=Decimal('2'))]
```